# psycopg2 blocks on 'connect' when inside a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking, psycopg2, python-multithreading

I'm working on building a web framework on top of Flask which includes a wrapper package for database operations with will work for both postgresql and MySQL (I prefer not using a third-party ORM and this will also help me learn a few concepts).

I will detail a small example of where the problem described in the title is ocurring. I managed to emulate the problem with a very succint group of modules:

c.py

```
#coding=utf-8
import threading
import psycopg2

class Pool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.push)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join()
    def push(self):
        print 'creating connection'
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(database='geocercas', user='geo', password='geow', host='localhost')
        print 'created connection'
    def get(self):
        return self.conn
```

b.py

```
#coding=utf-8
from c import Pool

pool = Pool()
```

a.py

```
#coding=utf-8
from b import pool
```

If I run b.py i get the result:

```
creating connection
created connection

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I run a.py I get:

```
creating connection
```

And it just hangs there.

I'm running Python 2.7.3 on Debian 7
Edit: Just to be clear, the block occurs when importing c from b, then b from a when c creates the connection inside a thread. If I don't use threads in c, a works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out I failed to read this little tidbit in the documentation which was the cause of the problem: [Importing in threaded code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code)